# How to dynamically mock ES6 modules with SystemJS?

Tags: testing, ecmascript-6, systemjs

I have a single-page application written in ES6. The code in transpiled server-side into classic javascript by babelJs, then loaded by SystemJs.

Javascript present in my html file:

```
System.config({
  baseURL: '/js',
  meta: {
    '/js/*': { format: 'cjs' }
  }});
System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
System.import("index.js")
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error)
    });
```

index.js:

```
import f1 from 'file1';
import f2 from 'file2';

// code here ...
```

Everything works fine. `index.js` is loaded, and all `import` statements are correctly executed.

Now, I want to create some pages with mocked ES6 modules, for testing purpose. My goal is to display pages by replacing model classes (contained in ES6 modules) with other static test classes.

Let's say I have 3 files: `real_model.js`, `fake_model.js` and `component.js`. `component.js` import the real model (`import Model from 'real_model';`).

How can I replace the real model by the fake one (in the component) dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was posted, but maybe this solution might still be of help to anyone else.

With SystemJS it is possible to create a module on-the-fly using `System.newModule`. Then you can use `System.set` to overwrite existing modules with the new one. In our tests we use the following helper function to mock existing modules:

```
function mockModule(name, value) {
  const normalizedName = System.normalizeSync(name);
  System.delete(normalizedName);
  System.set(normalizedName, System.newModule(Object.assign({ default: value }, value)));
}
```

Then, e.g. inside the beforeEach callback, we assign the mock and then import the module to be tested using `System.import`:

```
let [component, fake_model] = [];

beforeEach(() => {
  // define mock
  fake_model = { foo: 'bar' };

  // overwrite module with mock
  mockModule('real_model', fake_model);

  // delete and reimport module
  System.delete(System.normalizeSync('component'));
  return System.import('src/testing').then((m) => {
    component = m.default;
  }).catch(err => console.error(err));
});

// test your component here ...
```

A big advantage of this approach is that you don't need an additional mocking library and it works solely with SystemJS.